# Composer install is asking me user and password for a contrib module

Tags: 8, composer

I'm installing my own clone of a Drupal project and when I'm launching Composer Install, in the drupal/calendar, ask me an git.drupal.org id to download the module...what can I do?

[image]

Comment: It’s asking for your Drupal.org git credentials tied to your Drupal.org account.

Comment: What's written in your `composer.json`? Is it `"drupal/calendar": "1.x-dev",`?

Comment: Do you have anything for `git.drupal.org` in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, It is. Without a doubt.

Comment: @leymannx Yep! just the same

Comment: @Clive I don'tt think it is necessary to have ssh credentials for the repository doing Composer Install. Is it necessary for contrib modules in dev branch?

Comment: That’s my point - it’s definitely not required, but maybe you have ssh config overriding the default. Was just a thought, think it stung me once

Comment: Have you tried it at least once after removing the `composer.lock` file and any maybe existing vendor folders? Is there somewhere another `.git` folder inside the project, maybe even `web/modules/contrib/calendar/.git`?

Comment: Hello did you guys find the solution? I'm having exactly the same issue installing the dev version of Calendar..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer installing dev modules getting Authentication required (git.drupalcode.org)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299809/composer-installing-dev-modules-getting-authentication-required-git-drupalcode)

Comment: Make sure you have added your SSH key to your GitLab profile: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-authenticating-with-ssh-keys