# Composer installing dev modules getting Authentication required (git.drupalcode.org)

Tags: 8, composer

When trying to composer install, and it reaches one of the modules using a Dev version, I get:

`- Installing drupal/paragraphs (dev-1.x 42842d5): Authentication required (git.drupalcode.org): Username:`

I tried removing the `vendor` folder, I tried removing my `composer.lock` file, I tried updating my git, and I tried `composer clearcache`. Nothing worked.

Also, I tried `composer install` and `composer install --no-dev`, and both didn't work.

Anyone ever experiences this before? I never had this issue until today...I'm also using WAMP if that helps too.

Here's my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    { "type": "composer", 
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org" 
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
    "drupal/addtoany": "^1.14",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.2",
    "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.11",
    "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.5",
    "drupal/background_image": "^1.5",
    "drupal/bigmenu": "^2.0",
    "drupal/block_content_permissions": "^1.10",
    "drupal/calendar": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/captcha": "^1.1",
    "drupal/conditional_styles": "^1.0",
    "drupal/context": "^4.0",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
    "drupal/devel": "^4.0",
    "drupal/draggableviews": "^1.2",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^1.12",
    "drupal/entity_block": "^1.0",
    "drupal/eva": "^2.0",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
    "drupal/filefield_sources": "^1.0",
    "drupal/flexslider": "^2.0",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.5",
    "drupal/image_effects": "^3.0",
    "drupal/imce": "^2.2",
    "drupal/layout_builder_component_attributes": "^1.0",
    "drupal/libraries": "^3.0",
    "drupal/login_security": "^1.5",
    "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.3",
    "drupal/menu_block": "^1.6",
    "drupal/menus_attribute": "^1.1",
    "drupal/migrate_file": "^1.1",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.2",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.5",
    "drupal/migrate_upgrade": "^3.2",
    "drupal/mimemail": "^1.0",
    "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
    "drupal/override_node_options": "^2.5",
    "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0",
    "drupal/panelizer": "^4.4",
    "drupal/panels": "^4.6",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/password_policy": "^3.0",
    "drupal/pathauto": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/protected_pages": "^1.2",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
    "drupal/scheduler": "^1.3",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.17",
    "drupal/search_api_page": "^1.0",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.0",
    "drupal/security_review": "^1.0",
    "drupal/sidr": "^3.1",
    "drupal/smart_trim": "^1.3",
    "drupal/text_resize": "^1.1",
    "drupal/twig_field_value": "^2.0",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.6",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_field_view": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.7",
    "drupal/webform": "^5.16",
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.0",
    "kint-php/kint": "^3.3",
    "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "installer-types": ["npm-asset"],
    "patches": {
        "drupal/core": {
            "Call to a member function getColumns() on boolean": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-10-29/2893747-33.patch",
            "Call to a member function getTranslation() on null in ContentEntityBase": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-01-24/core-ContentEntityBase_getTranslation_on_null-3108528-2.patch",
            "system_update_8804() fails if any path alias is created before it runs": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-08-13/3098718-core.system_update_8804.truncate_path_alias_tables-69.patch"          
        },
        "drupal/panels": {
            "Custom attributes in panels blocks and variants": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-04-30/panels_custom_attributes_in_panels_blocks-2849867-78.patch"
        },
        "drupal/menu_block": {
            "Hide region when block menu is empty": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stef-van-looveren/drupal-8-patches/master/menu_block-8.x-1.5-empty-region.patch"
        },
        "drupal/pathauto": {
            "Custom aliases (which are not generated with the actual patterns) can be lost during the migration": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-11-17/pathauto-prevent_losing_custom_aliases-3079275-17--combined-with-3179835-and-3179865.patch"
        },
        "drupal/calendar": {
            "Node with calendar block wont display": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-12-11/fix_error_for_missing_url_from_view_display-2993422-2.patch"
        }
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "web/"
        },
        "file-mapping": {
            "[web-root]/robots.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/README.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/INSTALL.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/example.gitignore": false,
            "[web-root]/modules/README.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/profiles/README.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/themes/README.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/sites/README.txt": false,
            "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": false
        } 
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library",
            "type:npm-asset"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Same: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/271727/15055. What command did you run to require dev paragraphs? Can you also please add your composer.json to the question? Many thanks 

Comment: Hi leymannx! Sorry about that last post on drupal.stackexchange.com/q/271727/15055 lol!

I updated my OP. I have dev version of Paragraph and Calendar. I had Dev version of Paragraph alreaady installed before getting this issue. It only came up now because I removed my composer.lock file. Thanks! :)

Comment: Make sure you have added your SSH key to your GitLab profile: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-authenticating-with-ssh-keys

Comment: This issue also happens [if the WSL clock is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086856/wsl2-clock-is-out-of-sync-with-windows). Run `date` to check. The WSL clock will become out of sync with Windows if you put your computer to sleep with [Modern standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states#sleep-state-modern-standby), which is the default in Windows 11, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue happens when you are requesting packages through composer from corporate network. Corporate firewall blocks the network request. The credentials it is asking is actually for corporate proxy.

Just connect to open internet and try again your issue will be probably resolved.

Comment: Make sure you have added your SSH key to your GitLab profile: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-authenticating-with-ssh-keys

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! turns out my anti-virus is blocking `git.drupalcode.org/`. Had to add `git.drupalcode.org/*` to my whitelist.

Comment: Make sure you have added your SSH key to your GitLab profile: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-authenticating-with-ssh-keys